# How to install @vue/cli in docker image

Tags: docker, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to install @vue/cli into fresh docker image. Last time I did this half a year ago, I have succeed. But this time strange things happens.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN yarn global add @vue/cli
```

When I run `docker image build -t vue:alpine .` I get this kind of response:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/3 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> 5d187500daae
Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --no-cache git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54e50fd9dcb8
Step 3/3 : RUN yarn global add @vue/cli
 ---> Running in 79e4aa0bf291
yarn global v1.19.1
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "function-bind" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/global for documentation about this command.
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > nodemon > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching
 binaries from AWS, smaller package size
Error: Couldn't find package "arr-diff" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "array-unique" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "array-unique" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "array-unique" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "arr-diff" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "ajv" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "function-bind" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "array-unique" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "function-bind" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "function-bind" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "function-bind" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "json5" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "statuses" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "statuses" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "statuses" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "for-in" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "statuses" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:304:30)
    at /opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:315:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Error: Couldn't find package "function-bind" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at NpmResolver.<anonymous> (/opt/yarn-v1.19.1/lib/cli.js:50683:15)
```

I tried to find some of this packages at npmjs.com, and they are ok.
So looks like, something blocks `yarn` to connect to npm repo.

Does anyone had similar issue and how can it be fixed?

Little update:
I've tried similar thing with npm (Dockerfile):

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
```

And after a few minutes I've got:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.096kB
Step 1/3 : FROM node:lts-alpine
 ---> 5d187500daae
Step 2/3 : RUN apk add --no-cache git
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 54e50fd9dcb8
Step 3/3 : RUN npm install -g @vue/cli
 ---> Running in 9c8e21b3fcc7
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/statuses
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'statuses@>= 1.5.0 < 2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'http-errors'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-11-16T18_48_54_942Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install -g @vue/cli' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: For me it works,  im using debian 9 and docker 19.03   i did `docker pull node:lts-alpine` and then `docker build .` and then `docker run -it node:lts-alpine`

Comment: Well, I tried to install @vue/cli in a fresh container with 
`docker run -it node:lts-alpine yarn global add @vue/cli` as you mentioned, but got a same ton of errors/

Comment: can you please post your `docker -v` ?

Comment: It is `Docker version 19.03.4, build 9013bf583a`.
I assume that this is some kind of networking problem.

Comment: Are you using proxy ? if you just run the command `docker pull node:lts-alpine`? You can even try just to build the image and go inside the container and run thous commands. `docker run -it node:lts-alpine bash`

Comment: It's `/bin/sh` in the alpine instead of `bash`, but yeah, I used that.
I solved the issue by upgrading npm of the base image. Thanks for you attention.

Answer (score 1):

So i figured it out, the thing is a `npm` (and an `yarn` occasionally) supplied by `node` image. The current image `node:13.1.0-alpine` contains `npm version 6.12.0`

This is how I solved it:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache curl
RUN curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
RUN npm -v
```

Script used in this Dockerfile is provided by npm itself, and it installs newer version of npm into image. `npm version 6.13.1`

Than I just build it, and use it instead of the original image.

```
docker build -t node-updated .
docker run node-updated npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Although, it doesn't solve problem for `yarn`.

I'm pretty sure that this is a temporary problem with the `node` image since it will be updated soon. Hope somebody will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn is not installed by default.
By adding the following line inside the Dockerfile, you can install yarn.

```
RUN apk add yarn
```

The `apk` coommand is like `apt-get` or `yum`, but for alpine distribution.

When yarn is installed, you can add the following line to install vue-cli and vue-cli-service. In my case, I needed both.

```
RUN yarn global add @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global
```